# Can not submit a form via JS after Parsley validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, parsley.js

After Parsley says the form is valid, the modal dialog is being shown to the user with the Accept/Decline button. Once Accept is clicked, the form is supposed to be submitted, however it doesn't happen.

```
  // Show the modal dialog before signing up.
  $('form#new_user').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($('input#user_nda_accepted').val() !== 'true') {
      return false;
    }
  });

  $.listen('parsley:form:validated', function(formInstance) {
    if (formInstance.isValid()) {
      $('body').addClass('modal--open');
    }
  });

  // Submit the form on Accept, hide the modal on Decline.
  $('.js-nda-accept').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('input#user_nda_accepted').val('true');
    $('form#new_user').off('submit.Parsley').trigger('submit');
  });

  $('.js-nda-decline').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('input#user_nda_accepted').val('false');
    $('body').removeClass('modal--open');
  });
```

Comment: Well what *does* happen? Are there errors reported in the console? Have you traced through the code in the debugger to see which event handlers are being invoked?

Comment: No errors in the console. The `submit` callback specified above is being invoked. The `$._data($('form#new_user')[0], 'events')` returns an array with just that handler.

Comment: ... and I presume that the value of that input field is the string `"true"` (which I agree it should be, or at least I think it should). Maybe the HTML5 validation stuff is in a state that prevents the form from being submitted.

Comment: Actually no, the HTML5 validation stuff shouldn't prevent the form from being submitted via JavaScript.